# 2012 Dodge Caravan - Lubrication of door channel

Tags: lubrication, diy

Both the sliding doors make a grinding noise when opening or shutting down.

The place I take this to for an oil change claims to lubricate doors and windows. Now I am not too sure.

What level of knowlege do I need to fix the grinding noise? My mechanical skills are very limited to changing a flat tire and the wiper blades on my van.

**Edited:**
The car is no longer under warranty. I have a power-train warranty and I am not sure if it covers doors.

Comment: @MarkJohnson ... I'm sure since it's a 2012, they're both motorized.

Comment: They are motorized. I can control them from the switch on the keypad as well.

Comment: Is this thing still under warranty on the Bumper-to-Bumper? If so, take it back to Dodge and have them fix it. These should not be grinding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maintenance schedules says `At Each Oil Change`:

```
Open the left and right door (slowly) and inspect for excessive dirt. 
If noise exist wipe clean and apply krytox lube to the door rollers.
```

Not sure if that's referring to the front driver/passenger doors or the sliding doors.  I would break out the Mark I eyeballs and see if you can see any sign of lubrication and maybe apply some fresh Krytox to the moving parts and friction surfaces.  Of course, your problem could actually be grease contamination in the motor clutches, in which case more grease could just make it worse.  Possibly there could be some debris contamination, too.

Visual [guide](http://www.paulstravelpictures.com/Dodge-Grand-Caravan-Jammed-Side-Power-Sliding-Door-Repair-Guide/) for reference.

Comment: See, this is why you need to answer more often, Mark ;-)

Comment: Mark, Thank you for taking the time to answer. I am planning to get the vehicle inspected for tire-wear. At that time, I will ask the mechanic to check for the sliding doors.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Unfortunately in my area, I only know the big chain store mechanics. (Pep Boys, TiresPlus, etc...)

Comment: @MarkJohnson The issue is now resolved. I asked the mechanic to check for noises when the door slides. The guys at this NTB location were, surprisingly good. They lubricated and greased the door channels. The noise has ceased almost completely. I don't know what grease they used.